# Additional Model is undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I am having problems including an additional model into my view which is based on a collection. I have a list of comments which is created by a parent view. Its need that I have the current user name when rendering the comments to show delete button and to highlight if its his own comment. The problem is now that I cant access in CommentListView the model session, so this.session in initialize or a call from a method like addAllCommentTo list is undefinied. What I am doing wrong here? I thought its easily possible to add another object to an view appart from the model.

CommentListView:

```
window.CommentListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#comments"),

    initialize: function () {

        this.model.bind('reset', this.addAllCommentToList, this);
        this.model.bind('add', this.refresh, this);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.refresh, this);
    },

    refresh: function(){
        this.model.fetch();
    },

    addCommentToList : function(comment) {
        console.log("comment added to dom");
        //need to check why el reference is not working
        $("#comments").append(new CommentView({model:comment, sessionModel: this.session}).render().el);
    },

    addAllCommentToList: function() {
        $("#comments").empty();
        this.model.each(this.addCommentToList);
    }
});
```

Call from parent list in initialize method:

```
window.UserDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #newComment" : "newComment"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.commentText = $("#commentText", this.el);

        new CommentListView({ model: this.model.comments, session: this.model.session });


        new LikeView({ model: this.model.like });

        this.model.comments.fetch();

    },

    newComment : function() {

        console.log("new comment");
        this.model.comments.create(
            new Comment({text: this.commentText.val()}), {wait: true}
        );
        this.commentText.val('');
    }

});
```

Model:

```
window.UserDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot:'/api/details',

    initialize:function () {
        this.comments = new Comments();
        this.comments.url = "/api/details/" + this.id + "/comments";

        this.like = new Like();
        this.like.url = "/api/details/" + this.id + "/likes";

        this.session = new Session();

    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: How are you binding add, remove, reset to a model? These are collectin related events?

Comment: Can you please post rest of the code too about the models?

Comment: I added now the model and the complete parent view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem, but can there be others.

You are initializing the View like this:

```
new CommentListView({ model: this.model.comments, session: this.model.session });
```

And you are expecting into your View to have a reference like this `this.session`.

This is not gonna happen. All the hash you send to the View constructor will be stored into `this.options`, from [Backbone View constructor docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> When creating a new View, the options you pass are attached to the view as this.options, for future reference.

So you can start changing this line:

```
$("#comments").append(new CommentView({model:comment, sessionModel: this.session}).render().el);
```

by this other:

```
$("#comments").append(new CommentView({model:comment, sessionModel: this.options.session}).render().el);
```

Try and tell us.

#### Updated

Also change this line:

```
this.model.each(this.addCommentToList);
```

by this:

```
this.model.each(this.addCommentToList, this);
```

The second argument is the *context*, in other words: what you want to be `this` in the called *handler*.

Comment: `model: this.model.comments` and the `addAllCommentsToList` implementation suggest that the view's `this.model` is a collection and thus should be called `this.collection`. Other than that, you said pretty much what I was about to say.

Comment: @muistooshort indeed... I didn't want to add noise to the answer, each one is free to obfuscate his own code ;)

Comment: I tried with this.options.session but options is undefined as well. firebug is saying that this is Window

Comment: It is very weird that in that method (`CommentListView.addCommentToList()`) `this` is `window`, still check the update on my answer. If this change doesn't work confirm the line of the error and tell us who else is calling this method.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot! I am getting very often confused with the use of "this"

Comment: @Gambo: `this` is one of the most confusing things in JavaScript, until you get used to it of course.

Comment: Can this be avoided using coffee script?

Comment: @Gambo, the _special_ behavior of _this_ in JS is not a bug but a feature :).. as _mu_ said you have to get used to it (I have to say that it is still bothering me)